# How to change the floating action button color which touched in ionic1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have used the ion-floating-button in which i can change the color of the fab but when it is pressed or touched i couldn't get any highlight for the button is it possible to give highlight when the fab is pressed in ionic 1.

```
<ion-floating-button ng-click="vm.gotoNewFarmer()" has-footer="false" button-color="rgb(84, 44, 99)" icon="ion-plus" iconColor="#fff">
```

Answer (score 0):

style from angular js

```
<input type="button" value="set color" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
<input type="button" value="set background" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'blue'}">
<input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
<br/>
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
<pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
```